# StrictMode DiskReadViolation at auen.a(:com.google.android.gms@233717044)

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, google-ads-api, android-strictmode

***Description:*** I am only using com.google.android.gms packaged classes for AD Id and Remote config and all the code is being run on IO Dispatcher. I feel this is happening internally on Google's side. Still I want your inputs how this can be fixed from my side or whether it can be fixed or not?

***Full stack trace:***

```
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1659)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.stat(BlockGuardOs.java:419)
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.stat(ForwardingOs.java:846)
at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.stat(ActivityThread.java:8143)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getLength(UnixFileSystem.java:330)
at java.io.File.length(File.java:968)
at auen.a(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):25)
at aufq.e(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):252)
at aufq.b(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):450)
at auft.query(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):141)
at aevp.query(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):3)
at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1417)
at mgp.superQuery(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):2)
at com.google.android.chimera.ContentProvider.query(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):2)
at aevp.query(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):20)
at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1513)
at mgp.superQuery(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):1)
at com.google.android.chimera.ContentProvider.query(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):1)
at mgp.query(:com.google.android.gms@233717044@23.37.17 (190400-570218080):2)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:281)
at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:107)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1226)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1163)
# via Binder call with stack:
at android.os.StrictMode.readAndHandleBinderCallViolations(StrictMode.java:2497)
at android.os.Parcel.readExceptionCode(Parcel.java:2417)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:139)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:481)
at android.content.ContentProviderClient.query(ContentProviderClient.java:196)
at android.content.ContentProviderClient.query(ContentProviderClient.java:178)
at bau.a(PG:30)
at bkd.a(PG:1)
at aqp.run(PG:27)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
at qco.run(PG:4)
at qah.run(PG:3)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
at qdi.run(PG:5)
```

Comment: Would you care to share the code that is causing this?

Comment: I am not able to find which code is causing this. Stack trace doesn't show which part of my code is causing this. As mentioned I have verified all the code which uses com.google.android.gms packaged classes, and all of that code is being called from IO Dispatcher.